# Alguna forma de veriificar si el Correo es gmail o hotmail especificamente? al registrar un usuario?

Tags: php

Verna quiero saber si una pagina php puede permitir que solo correos gmail, hotmail, yahoo sean los disponibles para registrarse estuve leyendo pero no se como configurar esto de forma que al final haga die si el correo no es ninguno de los anteriormente nombrados.

```
<?? <?php 

function validar_email($email){ 

   $exp = "^[a-z\'0-9]+([._-][a-z\'0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([._-][a-z0-9]+))+$"; 

   if(eregi($exp,$email)){ 

   if(checkdnsrr(array_pop(explode("@",$email)),"MX")){ 
      return true; 
   }else{ 
      return false; 
   } 

   }else{ 

      return false; 

   } 
} 

// para aplicarla 

if (validar_email($_GET[correo])){ 
// coloco las instrucciones 
echo 'Es correcto el correo'; 
}else{ 
echo 'Es falso el correo'; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es primero verificando que el texto introducido sea un correo válido, esto para no dejar pasar espacios o algún carácter extraño. Si pasa la primera verificación, luego se calcula en qué posición está el @ y se extrae la subcadena desde esa posición hasta el final. Esa subcadena debería ser el dominio de correo, la cual se buscará en `$disponibles`. Si se encuentra, entonces el correo es válido.

```
<?php
function validar_email($email) { 
    $disponibles = array('gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com');
    $valid_email = False; // Se asume inicialmente que no cumple
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== False) {
        $at_pos = strpos($email, '@');
        $email_domain = substr($email, $at_pos+1);
        if(in_array($email_domain, $disponibles)) {
            $valid_email = True; // Si se encuentra en $disponibles
        } 
    }
    return $valid_email;
}
```

Prueba

```
var_dump(validar_email('usuario@gmail.com')); // True
var_dump(validar_email('usuario@php.net')); // False
var_dump(validar_email('usuario_yahoo.com')); // False
var_dump(validar_email('usuario200@yahoo.com.eu')); // False
var_dump(validar_email('usuario200@yahoo.com')); // True
```

Otra forma que puedes usar para limitar al usuario a usar solo esas opciones, es poner un `select` en tu formulario html con esas opciones, y posteriormente concatenar los dos campos una vez los captures.

```
<form action="..." method="...">
    ...
    Usuario de correo: 
    <input type="text" name="email_user" class="..." required>
    -@-
    <select name="email_domain" class="..." required>
        <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
        <option value="gmail.com">gmail.com</option>
        <option value="hotmail.com">hotmail.com</option>
        <option value="yahoo.com">yahoo.com</option>
    </select>
    ...
</form>
```